# How to prevent refresh after clicking the alert OK button? Return false doesn't work here

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, alert, reload

I have a form to update a user's profile and I want to alert users when they leave the password field blank.

Currently, when a user leaves the password field blank and submits the form, the alert box will come up. But after clicking the OK button on the alert, the page refreshes and somehow the user updates his password to blank...

Here's my code:

```
$userProfileForm.on("submit", handleUpdateUserProfile);
async function handleUpdateUserProfile(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const updatedUser = {
    name: $("#edit-user-name").val(),
    password: $("#edit-user-password").val(),
  };
  if (!updatedUser.password) {
    alert("Password can't be empty!");
    // not working. It still refreshes the page and set the password to empty
    return false;
  } else {
    currentUser = await currentUser.updateProfile(updatedUser);
    saveUserCredentialsInLocalStorage();
    return true;
  }
}
```

I also tried `e.preventDefault()` but it's not working as well. Please tell me how I can prevent the page reload. Thanks!

---

Edit:
I changed `return false` to `return true` and it works...but I received a warning in the console saying `[Violation] 'submit' handler took 1130ms   jquery:5229`
Could someone help me explain what's going on here?
Here's the new code:

```
$userProfileForm.on("submit", handleUpdateUserProfile);
async function handleUpdateUserProfile(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const updatedUser = {
    name: $("#edit-user-name").val(),
    password: $("#edit-user-password").val(),
  };
  if (!updatedUser.password) {
    alert("Password can't be empty!");
    // working now, the page doesn't refresh but receives a warning
    return true;
  } else {
    currentUser = await currentUser.updateProfile(updatedUser);
    saveUserCredentialsInLocalStorage();
    // I have to use reload() to force the page upload
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to return anything from that code. The e.preventDefault() should handle not submitting - [plain js](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vae8wpyL/) version  [jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ce40jyk9/) version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to return anything from that code. The e.preventDefault() should handle not submitting -

[plain js](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vae8wpyL/) version

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", asyncsubmit)

async function asyncsubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.querySelector("[name=q]").value === "") alert("Don't leave empty")
  else console.log(e.target.id)
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

[jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vae8wpyL/) version

```js
$("#myForm").on("submit", asyncsubmit)

async function  asyncsubmit(e)  {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.target).find("[name=q]").val() ==="") alert("Don't leave empty")
  else console.log(e.target.id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, mplungjan! I removed return true and this time it works fine...seems like I messed up with e.preventDefault() before (forgot to add parentheses ) But the console still gives me the warning, do you know why and how can I remove it? Thanks!

Comment: No idea. Seems the processing inside your handler takes a long time.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thank you anyway for solving my problem!